# Disable Roslyn Analyzer in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I wanted to know how do I disable all roslyn analyzers in entire solution during debug mode but keep them enable in release mode?
I can find references to disable them permanently or individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to the .csproj file of your project:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <RunAnalyzers>false</RunAnalyzers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will disable all analyzers for debug builds, but not for release builds.